# Code running fine locally but erroring when published live on GoDaddy

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-assembly

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data,
>   Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File: G:\PleskVhosts\dekhoroom.com\httpdocs\web.config    Line:
>   11
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: Well, have you deployed `MySql.Data` assembly to the hosting?

Comment: how to add on godady ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you, on your local development machine, have MySql.Data in your GAC, it will not be in your Web app's bin directory. And if it is that bin directory that gets deployed, Sql.Data will not be there. Do not expect a hosting provider to have all kinds of assemblies in the GAC.

So the solution is to deploy all the assemblies your Web app needs. Deploy MySql.Data, and any other assemblies that it depends upon, along with your Web application.

For the same reason, it is a good idea not to install ASP.NET MVC in your GAC but to simply reference it and deploy it along with your Web application.